# there is existing theme on github pages, how can I replace jekyll-theme?

Tags: github, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I forked some jekyll themes. So I have github io remote on my git account, now. However, I want to replace another theme. is it possible to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use custom Jekyll themes.

> To build your site with any public, GitHub-hosted theme, add the
>   following to your site’s `_config.yml` file:

```
remote_theme: owner/name
```

Replacing owner and name with the repository’s owner and name.

[How to use custom Jekyll themes in Github pages](https://blog.github.com/2017-11-29-use-any-theme-with-github-pages/)